# print 2d array based on the enum values

Tags: c#

Firstly I have an enum storing the c ConsoleColor values, I want to print a 2d array to the console such that it shows an '#' instead of the enum value based on the color set in the enum, I have been trying to so this for a while now but I couldent get anywhere any help will be much appreciated.

Here is my code

```
public enum CandyCrushCandies
{
    JellyBean = ConsoleColor.Red, 
    Lozenge = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan, 
    LemonDrop = ConsoleColor.Yellow, 
    GumSquare = ConsoleColor.Green, 
    LollipopHead = ConsoleColor.Blue, 
    JujubeCluster = ConsoleColor.Magenta 
}
```

method for displaying to the console

```
  void DisplayCandyCrushCandies(CandyCrushCandies[,] playingField)
    {
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CandyCrushCandies));
        Random rnd = new Random();
        CandyCrushCandies randomBar = (CandyCrushCandies)values.GetValue(rnd.Next(values.Length));

        string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(CandyCrushCandies), randomBar);
        var type = typeof(ConsoleColor);
      

        for (int row = 0; row < playingField.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < playingField.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                playingField[row, col] = (CandyCrushCandies)(ConsoleColor)type.GetProperty(name).GetValue(playingField[row, col]);
                Console.Write("# ", playingField[row, col]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

thanks a lot in advanced

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question, but i assume you were attempting to ask how to output **colorized** `#` characters to the console. Which shouldn't be too difficult, given that `System.Console` has properties both for setting the [foreground color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.foregroundcolor?view=net-6.0#System_Console_ForegroundColor) (text color) as well as the [background color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor?view=net-6.0#System_Console_BackgroundColor) of whatever is being printed by subsequent *System.Console.Write/WriteLine* calls.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you want to print rows and columns of '#' whose color is determined by another array:

```
void DisplayCandyCrushCandies(CandyCrushCandies[,] playingField)
{
   // I don't know what you want to do with this
   Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CandyCrushCandies));
   Random rnd = new Random();
   CandyCrushCandies randomBar = (CandyCrushCandies)values.GetValue(rnd.Next(values.Length));

   string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(CandyCrushCandies), randomBar);
   var type = typeof(ConsoleColor);
   //


   for (int row = 0; row < playingField.GetLength(0); row++)
   {
       for (int col = 0; col < playingField.GetLength(1); col++)
       {
          //playingField[row, col] = (CandyCrushCandies)(ConsoleColor)type.GetProperty(name).GetValue(playingField[row, col]);

          Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)playingField[row, col];
          Console.Write("# ");
       }
                Console.WriteLine();
   }
}
```